# overlapping of 2 html elements

Tags: html, asp.net, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

My goal is to make 2 elements side by side in html but when I try to do it they overlap slightly. Where am I failing?

```
 <div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-4"><img alt="100%x280" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ImgURL)" /></div>
 <div class="col-md-3"><span class="pull-right"><p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Plot)</p><p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Actors)</span></p></div>
```

[image]

Edit I have seen some examples here of similar questions but some use custom css and i would like to avoid that. Also i am using bootstrap!

Comment: without seeing your CSS it's really impossible to say. But probably something to do with margins, padding or floats.

Comment: Using default's for padding (Bootstrap), i am only changing colors with the custom one.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div class="col-md-4"><img alt="100%x280" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ImgURL)" /></div>
```

This line here. Change the bootstrap column from `4` to `5` or `6` to allow it more padding on the right side. This should easily fix your problem.

Comment: Oh I had done that but i thought it was a big no-no. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterKima you can accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Still 2 minutes to go. there is a lime limit on SO. Will do as soon as it become available.